# Android: How to prevent Broadcast from being lost on orientation change?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-lifecycle

My question is, if I rotate my device and a broadcast from the system for example from `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMEPLETE` gets sent between `onResume()` / `onPause()`, what is the best practice to prevent that broadcast from getting lost? Thanks.

```
onResume(){
  registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

// rotate device now

onPause(){
  unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

// broadcast gets sent now
```

Comment: check the status of your downloads in `onResume`, even if you lost the broadcast you can check it now

Comment: Try using a-manifest-declared `BroadcastReceiver` instead of the one registered within an `Activity`.

Comment: @pskink what if the broadcast is some information that I can't check on in `onResume`? like `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND`? If a bluetooth device is found while I am unregistered, how will I retrieve that lost device?

Comment: @mco in this case register your broadcast in a component that is always alive e.g. some service, also you could check `android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager` to get the status (never tried)

Comment: @pskink Thanks, that's what I was thinking as well. If you want to write up an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your Manifest.xml

> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```